# Im trying to get a .exe file to open whereever the folder is,

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to open an `.exe` file, but if I change the folder from desktop to another place I will get an error that the file could not be found.

```
start "" "%CD%
```

```bat
@echo off
color 0b
msg * Combo Tool by vFrEaKz Happy Cracking! ;)
echo Presiona cualquier tecla para continuar
pause >nul

:main
cls
echo off
echo Seleciona una opcion:
echo.
echo 1): Instalar VPN
echo 2): Abrir Leecher
echo 3): Abrir VPN
echo 4): Salir
echo.
set /p ch1=Opcion:
if not defined ch1 (
    echo Debes selecionar una opcion! goto main
)
if %ch1%==1 (
    goto 1
)
if %ch1%==2 (
    goto 2
)
if %ch1%==3 (
    goto 3
)
if %ch1%==4 (
    goto 4
)

:1
cls
start "" "%CD%\HQ Combo Tools by vFrEaKz\Tools\hqcombo.exe"
goto main
```

Comment: I understand the problem, I ran a treasure hunt once. After creating the maps and clues I decided to change the location of each of the items of treasure. For some reason I kept on getting messages from the participants stating that they couldn't find the treasure. The solution, apparently, is to wait until after you've moved something before you reference it's location!

Comment: I just want it to open hqcombo.exe no matter where its located.

Comment: Well stop moving it then! Perhaps you could add the location, of `HQ Combo Tools by vFrEaKz\Tools` to `%PATH%`.

Comment: Please remove your comment and edit the question to include the information.

Comment: You could place your batch file in the parent directory holding `HQ Combo Tools by vFrEaKz` and create a shortcut to it. Then in your batch file, use `Start "" "HQ Combo Tools by vFrEaKz\Tools\hqcombo.exe"` You may even consider creating a hard link, _see `MkLnk /?`_, for usage information. I think that the last resort would be to add code which walks the entire drive searching every file name on a system, trying to locate your file on every run of the script. At the very least you could have your script write the found location to a holding file, then read and check that location beforehand.

Comment: I fixed the issue, now i added this code to add music but how can i stop the music when i close the batch file? this is the code https://pastebin.com/XDTFkqNK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to search for your executable;

```
echo searching for hqcombo.exe...
for /r "C:\" %%a in (hqcombo.exe?) do set "hqc=%%a"
echo executing %hqc%:
"%hcq%"
```

Adapt `"C:\` to the folder you want to start the search. Might be `%~dp0` or `%cd%` or whatever. Note: the bigger the tree, the longer the search will take.
If you have more than one occurrence of `hqcombo.exe`, it will give you the last finding.

(Note: you *need* a wildcard (`hqcombo.exe?`) due to how `for /r` works.)

**EDIT**

after a lot of comments, it turned out, the file had the "Hidden" attribute and so couldn't be found. Deleting this attribute on the file (but keeping the folder "hidden") solved the problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185831/discussion-on-answer-by-stephan-im-trying-to-get-a-exe-file-to-open-whereever-t).

Comment: True, i did this and now it worked! thanks!, any info on how to put some backround music on this?